# how to find 2nd level of connections in neo4j?

Tags: neo4j

My neo4j graph shows like below..

- **300** is connected to **100**
- **100** is connected to **201** and **400**.

I want to find out the 2nd level of connectivity in neo4j.
For example: the 2nd level of node for **300** should return me **201** and **400**
**Is it possible in neo4j?**

[image]

[image]

when I use below cypher query:

```
MATCH (n)-[:CALLED*2]-(result)
WHERE n.name = '300'
RETURN result
```

It should give me only 201 and 400 ,but it return like below

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is very easy in Neo4j.  If you're using Cypher it might be something like:

```
MATCH (n)-[:CALLED]-()-[:CALLED]-(result)
WHERE n.id = 300
RETURN result
```

I'm assuming here that the `id` property is what is holding the identifying numbers, but obviously you can change that.

You can even do variable length paths like this:

```
MATCH (n)-[:CALLED*2]-(result)
WHERE n.id = 300
RETURN result
```

Part of the problem here, though, is that this will return node #200.  One query that would fit the result your looking for is:

```
MATCH (n)-[:CALLED]->()<-[:CALLED]-(result)
WHERE n.id = 300
RETURN result
```

This matches only where the middle node has the relationships pointing to it.

Comment: Good shout @brian-underwood. Is it worth pointing out to the OP that your first query will return many results if run against his example? They might want to match node **300** to 'anchor' the query. Also that by adding direction to the relationships it can refine the query further by restricting the graph traversal.

Comment: Right, duh, thanks!  I just edited with the assumption that the property storing those numbers is `id`

Comment: Hi Brian..Just changed the direction of a node....added the snapshot of graph..first 2 query gives me 4 nodes..instead it should return me only 201 and 400

Comment: @Aman - that is the expected result for your query. You are asking for nodes that are related to **300** by the relationship `:CALLED` and have a path length of 2. All the nodes returned match that pattern.

Comment: But My point was why the node 100 is displaying...Is it the neo4j considers node 100 as 2nd level, may be due to its connectivity in reverse direction...Now I am slowly getting the reason for showing the result.

Comment: Yes. Because it is the second level if the first node traversed is 200...that is why directionality becomes important.