# Identify second-level connections at scale

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'd like to identify second-level connections in a graph at scale, similar to [how to find 2nd level of connections in neo4j?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29764435/how-to-find-2nd-level-of-connections-in-neo4j)

Identifying second-level connections in Neo is straightforward, as in the accepted answer to that thread:

```
MATCH (n)-[:CALLED]->()<-[:CALLED]-(result)
WHERE n.id = 300
RETURN result
```

This works fine on my dataset, but I'd like a broader view. Essentially, I want to remove the WHERE in the above query, like so:

```
MATCH (n)-[:CALLED]->()<-[:CALLED]-(result)
RETURN n, result
```

Using Neo4j desktop, I get OOM errors running this second query. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Graph-wide queries can be expensive. If there is any way you can narrow down the work that would help, such as if the nodes should be only of particular labels.

You can also add a predicate on the ids of the nodes returned so you don't get mirrored results (same nodes but swapping the variable they are bound to):

```
MATCH (n)-[:CALLED]->()<-[:CALLED]-(result)
WHERE id(n) < id(result)
RETURN n, result
```

You may want to also check how much memory is available on your machine, and how much is configured for Neo4j's heap use. See the [memory configuration documentation](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/performance/memory-configuration/).

Comment: Thanks @InverseFalcon, the `id()` filter helped some. I still ended up having to narrow down the results more to avoid querying the whole graph after adding more memory.